# Generate array with with range of integers

Tags: arrays, go, range, slice

I have two values:

> [3:6]

I was trying to play something around in Golang but I can't manage to find a good method to create an array according to those values.

This what I would like to achieve:

```
[3,4,5,6]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of the `for ... range` construct to make it more compact and maybe even faster:

```
lo, hi := 3, 6
s := make([]int, hi-lo+1)
for i := range s {
    s[i] = i + lo
}
```

As a matter of curiosity, the loop can be implemented without a loop variable, but it will be slower, and the code longer. By decrementing `hi`:

```
for ; hi >= lo; hi-- {
    s[hi-len(s)+1] = hi
}
```

Or incrementing `lo`:

```
for ; lo <= hi; lo++ {
    s[len(s)-1-hi+lo] = lo
}
```