# Go: Get all the numbers/letters range between two limits

Tags: go

I am new to Go. I have 2 questions:

1. Is there a way to get all the numbers between a range in Go? I can do `range(1, 10)` in Python or `1 to 10` in Scala to get a range.
2. How to get all the alphabets  in go? Like Python's `string.letters` and `string.ascii_lower`.

Comment: What do you want to do? You can define any of those very easily.

Comment: You can the answers here:
1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21950244/is-there-a-way-to-iterate-over-a-range-of-integers-in-golang
2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17575840/better-way-to-generate-array-of-all-letters-in-the-alphabet

Comment: @JimB Writing an application that involves base62 encoding. 
Yes, I can but I believe this should be included in language. I don't want to define every time I need those. Isn't its available in Go?

Comment: @LuizdePrá I don't know how those questions are related to this. I don't want to iterate over a range. I want to get a list of numbers/letters between a range in Go.

Comment: I don't think anyone considers these things as critical as you do. https://play.golang.org/p/ruV_CjSK5r. I think the problem may lie more in trying to write python in Go, rather than getting the values you need. Having a slice of ints or a string of ascii letters wouldn't necessarily be used in Go like you use it in python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate array with with range of integers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35704948/generate-array-with-with-range-of-integers/35705756#35705756).

Answer (score 4):

Go doesn't provide a lot of syntactic sugar. You just have to write what those Python and Scala functions do for you.

```
for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
    fmt.Print(i)
}
for i := 'A'; i <= 'Z'; i++ {
    fmt.Printf("%c", i)
}
for i := 'a'; i <= 'z'; i++ {
    fmt.Printf("%c", i)
}
```

12345678910ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

https://play.golang.org/p/SU0uFVIg0k